" Then shall the wicked be revealed" 2Thes.2 .8; could the "wicked" (one ) possibly be speaking of the many?
In know (G459) is used in a singular, but I suspect that the "wicked" in this verse are a collective group, identified with a singular word. When I follow the same construction, which occurs in Rom.9.21; where law is used in a singular form; but which law, has many laws, kind of like how sheep can mean the many, while being used in singular form. I have many other grammatical reasons for this suspicion, but I feel it is not necessary for one to answer if this is a possibility?

2 Thess 2 is often called Paul's apocalypse because it describes the coming of the "Man of Lawlessness" in the following terms:

V3: Let no one deceive you in any way, for it will not come until the rebellion occurs and the man of lawlessness—the son of destruction—is revealed.
V4a: He will oppose and exalt himself above every so-called god or object of worship.
V4b: So he will seat himself in the temple of God, proclaiming himself to be God.
V6: And you know what is now restraining him, so that he may be revealed at the proper time.
V8: And then the lawless one will be revealed, whom the Lord Jesus will slay with the breath of His mouth and annihilate by the majesty of His arrival.
V9: The coming of the lawless one will be accompanied by the working of Satan ...

Note that all these nouns and pronouns are singular and personal.  Now it is indisputable that the Bible often talks about a power or nation in the singular by simply addressing the king or leader.
Thus, "The Man of Lawlessness" is possibly a leader who has a significant number of people and forces (all satanic according to V9) supporting him.

I don't see "him" G846, in the greek in verses 7-8, seems like the lord will show who the wicked are at His coming

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - some of the pronouns are implicit in the verbs and must be made explicit in English.

So your saying it's a grammatical assumption; let's say there are some other ways of understanding the meaning of this text. Is there a possibility that the wicked is not the same as the son of perdition, but rather the deceivers to whom Paul warns about in the previous verses.

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - no - I am saying that some of the pronouns are required when translating to English because of the grammar of the verbs.

In your conclusion I noticed that you mentioned,   a power or nation being represented by a leader why did you focus on that point

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - that is for completeness because of the fact of the Hebrew idiom - look at the prophecies of Dan 2 where the king stands for his kingdom.

@Dottard What was different in verses. 6 & 7 that you excluded the 'he's. Are the 2 'he's in verse 7 exclusive based on the colon and mystery of iniquity coming before the colon? Thanks for your answer in advance.

@RHPclass79 - the "he" in V7 is a different referent to that in V6.  Specifically, "he" in V6 is the lawless one", and the "he" in V7 is the one restraining the lawless one.

@Dottard That's the part that in my study never fit. It seemed to me that katecho was consistently used as identifieing the one who withholdeth or opposes. The context associates this with the son of perdition, man of sin, one who is revealed ( verses 4-6). In the the book of Daniel Michael holdeth with the 'the certain man's of Ch.10:5. If holdeth means help or support then withholdeth means the opposite to oppose , which is what the prince of Persia did 21 days. I see the son of perdition continuing to oppose until he is taken out of the way. Jesus's true brightness at his second coming does

@RHPclass79 - If something ion the Bible does not "fit" then one is looking at it in the wrong way.  I agree that two people are in view - one who restrains the man of sin and the man of sin himself.

The restrainer will, intill in the mist be fulfilled,  not taken, the restrainer in the mist is the 13 constellation that's was added back in the zodiac, next to virgo 2010, 2011 nation against nation  Egypt Civil War quote Isa.19.2 happened. Crazy interpretation right in am telling you. At least see the Greek. But my issue is with coming it's not taking about the man of sin its Christ's coming that is "against" in the greek the power of Satan

@RHRclass79 what where you talking about, dottard excluded he's I don't know where?
